# pdo sqlsrv sort by multiple columns

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sqlsrv

In mssql_query you can use a query like `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY value1 DESC, value2 DESC`. I am unable to do this with pdo sqlsrv.

What is the correct way of sorting the query results by multiple columns?

Sample data

```
|----------------------------------------|
|    id           value1        value2   |
|----------------------------------------|
|    4             119            21     |
|    2             115            17     |
|    1             114            10     |
|    3             104            21     |
|----------------------------------------|
```

Currently they're in the order of 4, 2, 1, 3, but they should be 4, 2, 3, 1.

Comment: Why "I'm unable to do this with pdo sqlsrv"? You get any error? If yes please add it to your question.

Comment: No errors. It feels like the second value2 DESC gets completely ignored.

Comment: Can you show sample data?

Comment: @Jens Added sample data to the thread.

Comment: But this is the right order. First oder by value1 and if value1 is equals then order by value2. So you should Change the order statement to `ORDER BY value2 DESC, value1 DESC`

Comment: It goes completely messed up when I change it ORDER BY value2 DESC, value1 DESC. It's a bit hard to explain, but this is a game database. The value1 is the character level and value2 is characters job. Job values 1-13 are the 1st and 2nd jobs. After player reaches level 120, they get brought back to level 60 but they receive a new job that has values 16-23. The point is, those who have value2 (job) set to 16 or above should be at the top of the query, even if their value1 (level) is lower than those whose value2 (job) is 1-13.

Comment: I can't understand why 3 is before 1 value1 of 3 is lower than value1 of 1? I think that can not be done by SQL because it is not a logic sort result.

Comment: Check out EDIT2 in my answer to see how to achieve a 4, 2, 3, 1 sort that you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are sorting, Any sorting done after the first sort only affects the ordering when value1 has two of the same values. I have created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a046b6/1) to show how sorting affects the order of data.

EDIT: I have created a [second fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85167f/1) (combined with the first ones results) that shows how distinct values on the first sort column with result in the second sort column to have no affect.

EDIT2: Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b5dc/6) that does what the OP wants to do. It groups job levels from 16 to 23 and assigns them a value of 2 and all other levels get a value of 1. Then it sorts on the Character level then if 2 characters have the same level it sorts based on Job level. sqlsrv formatted fiddle can be [found here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb9f1a/1)